# How can I combat all of these brute force attacks?

Tags: centos, brute-force-attacks

I have 3 dedicated servers, all running CentOS that are physically located in Canada.

On the newest server, cPHulk started detecting (and blacklisting) failed login attempts. It started the day that the server was put online. Since then, I get 15-30 emails daily from cPHulk letting me know it that there has been a "large number of failed login attempts".

I noticed that all of the attempts were coming from China, so I installed csf and blocked China entirely. A couple of days later, the attacks were back but from different countries. So far I've blocked four countries out of desperation, but I know that it's not a legitimate fix. Now they're coming from countries that I cannot afford to block because I can expect legitimate traffic from those countries.

I am also getting attacks from IPs that don't seem to be associated with a country, like in this screenshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LN6qmfK.png]

I am not worried that they'll be able to guess the password since the password I use is very strong.

So my questions are, **why are they targeting my server and how did they find it so quickly? How can I mitigate these login attempts without blocking entire countries? And where is that IP from in the screenshot?** My only guess is that somehow I've been assigned an IP with a terrible reputation, but my server admin experience and knowledge is a bit limited so I don't even know the plausibility of that.

Comment: You aren't being targeted. They're doing this to every IPv4 address on the Internet.

Comment: Precisely as Michael Hampton says above, but a mere upvote on the comment is not worthy of making the point strongly enough on this topic; every IPv4 address on the internet is subject to this type of attack.

Comment: This is why you should never have your SSH server on port 22, nor have password authentication turned on for external networks.

Comment: `0.42.0.0` sounds like a bug in the tool you are using to parse the log file. What does it say in the actual log file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Michael Hampton said, They [TM] do this to everyone.  Their scripts have detected an IP address listening on a port and they're throwing usernames and passwords at it to see if anything sticks.  [This](http://map.ipviking.com/) is a map of live attacks.

If the emails bother you, you can instead whitelist allowed login IPs and have it email you when someone logs in from a site that's not on the whitelist.

As for the IP in the screenshot, [0.42.0.0](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-0-0-0-0-1/pft):

> The address 0.0.0.0 may only be used as the address of an outgoing
>   packet when a computer is learning which IP address it should use. It
>   is never used as a destination address. Addresses starting with "0."
>   are sometimes used for broadcasts to directly connected devices.
>
> If you see addresses starting with a "0." in logs they are probably in
>   use on your network, which might be as small as a computer connected
>   to a home gateway.
>
> This block was assigned by the IETF, the organization that develops
>   Internet protocols, in the Standard document, RFC 1122, and is further
>   documented in the Best Current Practice document RFC 6890. IANA is
>   listed as the registrant to make it clear that this network is not
>   assigned to any single organization.
>
> These documents can be found at:
>   http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1122
>   http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6890

Answer (score 3):

I'm suprised nobody brought that up but a drastic way to get yourself out of these very common brute force attacks is to set up a port knocking daemon like [`knockd`](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock). Thus, unless the attacker scans your machine with a specific sequence of ports in the correct order, it won't even find an SSH port open. For legitimate users, many SSH clients support this and are able to trigger the correct port sequence before connecting to the ssh server.

But obviously, non trivial authentication with a running fail2ban jail and  appropriate find and ban times is sufficient in almost all cases.

Comment: Mind to explain the downvote ?

Answer (score -3):

If it's only about `sshd` - look e.g. here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21639/internet-ssh-server-security-considerations.

I must rely on using username and password, not keys. To be safer, I start the `sshd` at a non standard port, that seems to hinder about > 99% or so of attacks. Then, set `LoginGraceTime` in your sshd configs to, let's say `10` <strike>That means, after 3 failed attempst the next attempt can only be made after 10 seconds</strike> which gives any authentification attempt 10 seconds before closing the connection. <strike>So, brute force is no more *that* forceful :)</strike>.Also make sure to set `PermitRootLogin no`.

Comment: You got it all wrong.

Comment: there is no security through obscurity. changing the port only stops someone doing a flyby scan on only port 22. It wouldn't stop someone who actually wanted to target you. Timeouts only slow down someone using bruteforce not a shell exploit or another exploit

Comment: Yeah I know "no security through obscurity" and I didn't want to change the port at first. But my experience is that changing the port stops most stupid,brute force attackers. Re timeouts: that's why I said "if it's only about sshd".

Comment: @xavier-lucas Reading the headline question "How can I combat all of these brute force attacks?" I don't think so. Reading the emphasized questions at the end of question - you're right.

Comment: @dr0i That's not even that. Your answer is simply wrong in everything. `ConnectTimeout` is a client side option which indicates the maximum time tolerated to establish a connection to a remote ssh server. It has nothing to do with failed attempts or security in any way, it relates to link latency. Using login and password together is the best way to get yourself into continuous bruteforce attempts from botnets. Also changing the port won't make security better and is a pain for users. The actual way to avoid bruteforce for SSH access is to use keypairs with port knocking and/or iptables rules.

Comment: Oh, right. It was "LoginGraceTime", corrected that. As for the rest, I agree.

Comment: @dr0i Again, `LoginGraceTime` has nothing to do with security. This is the maximum tolerated time for a user to log in before the server drops its connection. The only relevant native option of the ssh daemon to this question is `MaxAuthTries` which lock a user account after the specified amount of failed attempts, but this means it impact legitimate users too.

Comment: Thank you for take the time to correct me. I messed it up pretty much.

Comment: @Drifter104 Moving sshd to a non-standard port is certainly not a way to secure a system. But it can reduce the noise in logfiles.